# SWIFT Firebase Realtime Database pagination double fetch issue

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

When I use following pagination method, sometimes I fetch double result, sometimes the pagination doesn't work. I would like to know what the issue is and what the best-practice is for Firebase Realtime Database pagination.

My user data structure:

```
"users" 
|- autoId1
     |- name: "abc"
     |- age: "22"
     |- ...
|- autoId2
     |- name: "xyz"
     |- age: "29"
     |- ...
|- autoId3
     |- name: "bbb"
     |- age: "20"
     |- ...
```

And I have a collection of classes, each class has numbers of students:

```
"class"
   |- "autoId" //this is the autoId for class
     |- autoId1: 1  //these are students autoId
     |- autoId2: 1
     |- autoId3: 1
```

When I fetch the students in a class I have the following code:

```
private var currentKey = nil
private func fetchUsersAtClass() {
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    if currentKey == nil {
          //classId is the autoId for a class
        CLASS_USERS.child(classId).queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
         guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else {return}
         guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                let uid = snapshot.key
               //fetch users from the users collection based on the [userId] fetched from class collection
                Database.fetchUser(with: uid, completion: { (user) in
                    self.users.append(user)
                    self.users.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                        return p1.credit > p2.credit
                    })
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })
            self.currentKey = first.key
        }
    } else {
        CLASS_USERS.child(classId).queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: currentKey).queryLimited(toLast: 4).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
            guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            
            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                let uid = snapshot.key
                if uid != self.currentKey {
                    Database.fetchUser(with: uid, completion: { (user) in
                        self.users.append(user)
                        self.users.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                            return p1.credit > p2.credit
                        })
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            })
            self.currentKey = first.key
        })
    }
}
```

For trigger pagination I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if users.count > 4 {
            if indexPath.item == users.count - 1 {
                fetchUsersAtClass()
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'usersBiz' come from?

Comment: I had corrected it. It should be users

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `.queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: currentKey)` is is actually expected that the node with `currentKey` gets retrieved for both the previous page and the current page. You'll have to remove that in your application code.

A new [`queryEnding(beforeValue:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#queryendingbeforevalue:) method was recently added to the API, which allows you to not get the overlapping entry.

Comment: Thanks.I will try queryEnding(beforeValue:)

Comment: I went through the documentation, I will search GitHub and give a try tonight.If it works I will upvote your post for sure

Comment: Do you happen to know some examples that use this method in GitHub?

Comment: It works the exact same was as `queryEnding(atValue:)`, but just doesn't return the node with the key you passed in.

Comment: incorrect argument label in call (have 'beforeValue:', expected 'atValue:') when I used it. I have updated my firebase to the newest version